# Saving BERT Sentence Embedding

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, information-retrieval

I'm currently working on an information retrieval task. I'm using SBERT to perform a semantic search. I already follows the documentation [here](https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/semantic-search/README.html)

The model i use

```
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2')
```

The outline is

1. You have a list of corpus like this:

```
    data = ['A man is eating food.',
          'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
          'The girl is carrying a baby.',
          'A man is riding a horse.',
          'A woman is playing violin.',
          'Two men pushed carts through the woods.',
          'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
          'A monkey is playing drums.',
          'A cheetah is running behind its prey.'
          ]
```

2. You have a query like this:

```
queries = ['A man is eating pasta.']
```

3. Perform encoding with both query and corpus

```
query_embedding = model.encode(query)
doc_embedding = model.encode(data)
```

the encode function outputs a numpy.ndarray like this
[outputs of model.encode(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Bjs.png)

4. And calculates the similarity using cosine similarity like this

```
similarity = util.cos_sim(query_embedding, doc_embedding)
```

5. And if you print the similarity, you'll get the torch.Tensor containing score of similarity like this

```
tensor([[0.4389, 0.4288, 0.6079, 0.5571, 0.4063, 0.4432, 0.5467, 0.3392, 0.4293]])
```

And it works fine and fast. But ofcourse it is only using a small amount of corpus. When using a large amount of corpus it will take time for the encoding to work.

note: The encoding of query takes no time because it is only one sentence, but the encoding of the corpus will take some time

So, the question is can we save the doc_embedding locally, and use it again? especially when using a large corpus

is there any built-in class/function to do it from the transformers?

Answer (score 3):

Save them as **pickle files** and load them later = ]

```
import pickle

with open('doc_embedding.pickle', 'wb') as pkl:
    pickle.dump(doc_embedding, pkl)

with open('doc_embedding.pickle', 'rb') as pkl:
    doc_embedding = pickle.load(pkl)
```

Comment: What if we want to add more embeddings/more data to our corpus? Can we just add the vector or we must do all of the embeddings (the old one and the addition) again?

Comment: you can simply add them without any problem. try `torch.cat` = ]

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with a big corpus you need to use a vector database, I wrote a few guides on Faiss [here](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/faiss-tutorial/) and [here](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/composite-indexes/) that you might find useful. Faiss does require a lot of learning to get reasonable performance, and only stores the vectors (not any other information like IDs, text, etc), so you would need to set up another database like SQL to handle that.

From experience, that can be super annoying. So I'd recommend looking into a managed vector database like [Pinecone](https://www.pinecone.io/docs/quickstart/), you can get that up and running from where you are now in ~10 minutes - it's free up to around 1M vectors, and performance is incredible.

Comment: What if we want to add more embeddings/more data to our corpus? Can we just add the vector or we must do all of the embeddings (the old one and the addition) again?

Comment: Yes, Pinecone supports adding new vectors to the database.